# How to allow users to list files, but not read the contents?

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions

The context of this question is data privacy.

We have a mostly automated system handling files containing **personal data**.

Because of that, *"ordinary"* users shall not be allowed to **read** the contents of those files.

However, such users may occasionally have to look at the folders, to clear out erroneous files or some backlog that wasn't processed.

For that the users must be able to **list** the folder contents, and **delete** files (both of which are completely unproblematic from the privacy point of view).

They shall, however, **not** be able to take ownership, change attributes, or open the files.

Can this be achieved?

From my experiments so far, it looks like the "list/read" permission on folders makes the files invisible?

Comment: I'd NEVER give such a permission to users (list file names and delete), just seems too odd. If identifying erroneous files is so obvious, that it's enough to read just it's file name, then you should have a script doing the job. Otherwise list file names in Excel and let users choose file names there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grant the "List/Read" and "Delete Child" permissions in "Container Inherit" mode (so that it applies to folders only):

```
icacls mydir /grant User:(CI)(R,DC)
```

In the graphical interface this is called "Apply to: This folder and subfolders", but you'll have to do without screenshots for now.

You can optionally grant the "Delete" permission (although it's redundany when the folder has "Delete Child" allowed), and/or deny the "Read" permission (just to be on the safe side) to files only, i.e. the "Object Inherit" mode:

```
icacls mydir /deny User:(OI)R
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the "Deny read" actually does the trick. Simply not having "Grant read" is obviously not the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: On its own, it _would_ be the same thing. It doesn't work only because the same "Read" permission is being granted by _another_ ACE (e.g. maybe you have `Everyone:R` or `Administrators:R` or something).